# Check 2 string equality and nullibility in one conditional statement

Tags: java

I am using below code to check if 2 strings are equal but before comparing string I need to make sure that string one is not null (while string2 is constant and it can not be null). To get this I am using below code

```
if(string1 != null && string1.equals(string2)) {

}
```

Is there any possible way in java to check that in one statement? I mean checking null and equality in single condition.

Comment: Note that this *is* one statement already - it's a single `if` statement. I suspect you mean "without the `&&`", or "with a simpler expression".

Comment: Yes I meant without && operator

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, turn it around. Since `string2` cannot be null, use

```
if(string2.equals(string1)){
  ..
}
```

This code

- Cannot result in a `NullPointerException` (assuming that `string2` *really* never is null)
- Returns `false` in case `string1` is `null`
- Also checks for equality

Comment: O woow that is great!! this is what I was looking for thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use Objects#equals:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#equals-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-

```
Objects.equals("s1", "s1") ==> true
Objects.equals(null, "s1") ==> false
Objects.equals("s1", null) ==> false
Objects.equals(null, null) ==> true
```

Comment: and what will the result with null values be?

Comment: While this is a valid answer in terms of being one statement, the implementation of that method is ``(a==b) || (a!=null && a.equals(b))``, so the code being executed is actually more "complex" than the existing one.

Comment: was execution time the main point here? I understood it as _easier to read_, not _faster to execute_. From a readability point of view, I prefer this option as it is a more global answer for a common problem - you don't rely on the fact that you know _for sure_ that string2 is not null.